# How do I display the query time when a query completes in Vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica, vsql

When using vsql, I would like to see how long a query took to run once it completes. For example when i run:

```
select count(distinct key) from schema.table;
```

I would like to see an output like:

```
5678
(1 row)
total query time: 55 seconds.
```

If this is not possible, is there another way to measure query time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `vsql` type:

```
\timing
```

and then hit Enter. You'll like what you'll see :-)

Repeating that will turn it off.

Comment: I assume you meant to type "vsql" instead of "vsqk".

Comment: be aware that this is the vsql client's local timing (so this time would also include any time your query spent queuing waiting for its turn on the database server-side)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the other part of your question:

> is there another way to measure query time?

Vertica can log a history of all queries executed on the cluster which is another source of query time. Before 6.0 the relevant system table was QUERY_REPO, starting with 6.0 it is `QUERY_REQUESTS`.

Assuming you're on 6.0 or higher, `QUERY_REQUESTS.REQUEST_DURATION_MS` will give you the query duration in milliseconds.

Example of how you might use `QUERY_REQUESTS`:

```
    select *
    from query_requests
    where request_type = 'QUERY'
    and user_name = 'dbadmin'
    and start_timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE
    and request ilike 'select%from%schema.table%'
    order by start_timestamp;
```

The `QUERY_PROFILES.QUERY_DURATION_US` and `RESOURCE_ACQUISITIONS.DURATION_MS` columns may also be of interest to you. Here are the short descriptions of those tables in case you're not already familiar:

`RESOURCE_ACQUISITIONS` - Retains information about resources (memory, open file handles, threads) acquired by each running request for each resource pool in the system.

`QUERY_PROFILES` - Provides information about queries that have run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to enable that in vsql or if that's possible. But you could get that information from a script.

Here's the psuedocode (I used to use perl):

```
print time
system("vsql -c 'select * from table'");
print time
```

---

Or put time into a variable and do some subtraction.

The other option is to use some tool like Toad to connect to Vertica instead of using `vsql`.